# How to Represent Foreign Keys in Java Objects

Tags: java, class, object, foreign-keys

If I have an entity class “Task” that in the database has a foreign key column to “Orders”, how should this be represented in code? Should the “Task” class have an “Order” object as one of its private fields and part of its constructor? Or does it not need to be there at all and I can just instantiate an “Order” object when it is needed?

Comment: Hi there. By foreign key you mean that Tasks and Orders are entity classes that represent Sql tables?

Comment: Hi Martin, yes that is correct. I should have made that more clear. I edited the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Well it depends on how you're doing the mapping of the tables into entities.

Tipically a table "foo" with foreign keys to a "bar" table will be represented as Foo and Bar java classes. Foo will hold a reference to the Bar class.

If you use a framework like Hibernate, you'll see something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="foo")
public class Foo {

    //...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="bar_id", nullable=false)
    private Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar b) {bar = b;}

    // getters and setters
}
```

This signals that the foo table has a bar_id column which points to a bar table entry.

The Foo entity holds a reference to the Bar entity.

Wether if you use hibernate or if you work with the DB manually (with a DAO pattern for example) it's recommended that you have a constructor that receives the "foreign" entity.

Check these links for more information:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Hope this helps, welcome to stack overflow

Comment: Thank you so much Martin for a detailed and helpful answer. In my particular case, many of my tables have foreign keys to entries in a “Companies” table, because I am building a SaaS app where companies are the primary entity. So it’s okay to have all these other entities hold reference to the “Company” entity?

Comment: Well you need to analyse the relationships between the tables. If a company holds many employees then you have a ManyToOne relationship between employee and company which can be expressed with @ManyToOne annotations with JPA and Hibernate. If that's the case then it's ok for the Employee entity to hold a reference to the Company entity. Apply this same logic to the rest of the tables and entities

If answer was helpful pls upvote and mark as correct